# Shared Vagrant configuration across multiple projects

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I have a few services, each one living in its own Git repository.

Each service is self-contained and runs independently from each other.

I want them to run in the same VM.

How do you use Vagrant to set up a shared development environment containing these services?

(Please note that I want to avoid creating a Vagrantfile per repo.)

Comment: can you run deploy the services in docker and then the VM will provision docker ? or you create a VM and pull each of the services from the different repo

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The problem with your approach is that I need to keep the vm in sync with the repos in my local machine (outside the vm). And to add in more complexity, I don't want to compile and deploy my services (and then pull them from the vm). The reason is that I am using an interpreted language that doesn't require a compile-deploy cycle, like Java for example, to debug/test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cookbook/puppet manifest or shell provisioner that will checkout individual git repository and run the service.

More details/configuration options for provisioners in Vagrant can be found
here

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.html

Comment: That could work, but I have an extra restriction. Each repo has their own custom configuration in files that are being excluded in .gitignore files. Since I want to automate the development environment setup, it would be necessary to keep these repos (and their individual configurations) in sync with /vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is just set up Beaker.  Find a mature module on the Puppet Forge for guidance.  You'll need `spec/spec_helper_acceptance.rb`, `spec/acceptance/nodesets/default.yml`, and you'll need the system tests selection of Gems from `Gemfile`.

Now create a file `spec/acceptance/yourclass_spec.rb`, and have it just apply your class to configure the VM in the way you want it.

To address the requirement of multiple projects in multiple git repos, you can install them all from within `spec/spec_helper_acceptance.rb`.

Alternatively, you can set up `.fixtures.yml` and `puppetlabs_spec_helper`, and run `bundle exec rake spec_prep` from within your spec helper.

To get your head around it clone some Forge module like `puppetlabs/apache`.

```
bundle install
export BEAKER_destroy=no
bundle exec rspec spec/acceptance/some_spec.rb
```

After the test finishes you can log in to your VM.

It's a bit of a learning curve, but it this way means you've got a way of quickly provisioning VMs, and you can test them properly too.

Beaker can even spin up multiple VMs so you could have all your services running together if you need to.

Comment: What if I need to manually inspect and debug the services while they run on the VM, and not only run the tests?

Comment: That's what exporting BEAKER_destroy=no achieves.  After the tests complete, the VMs remain and you can access them with vagrant global-status, then vagrant ssh.

Comment: That's pretty cool, if you are using Ruby. I will take it into account for future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe I miss something but sounds like you can run a VM and just use shared folder with the different folders with the services you are working on.

shared folder can take **absolute path** (not just relative in the current project where you define your Vagrantfile) so you can have a mixture of folders like

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = xxx
  blablabla

  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/fhenri/project/service1", "/project/service1"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/fhenri/project/examples/service2", "/project/service2", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/fhenri/project/ruby/service3", "/opt/rubyservice"
```

so when you provision this VM you can provision each of your service. as the folders are shared with the source of your project, any change you made in the original folder will be synced on the VM

you can also define multiple machines within this single Vagrantfile and have a shared folder in each of the machine

drawback: you cannot really share this Vagrantfile as the absolute path is mainly aligned with your own setting (you can use user_variable and so on but its not ideal)

Comment: This can work out. The drawback you mention can be overcome by creating a bootstrap script that developers must run before running vagrant the first time (maybe the script can run vagrant itself). I agree that this is not the best approach if you want to share this configuration with the team, though.

Comment: Right there could be solution depending your needs but I guess this is simple enough to work for your general case

Answer (score 0):

One approach involves using Vagrant and Git subtrees to reference and checkout the external components from a single repo.

Let’s suppose we have three different repos, service-auth, service-notifier and core, each one containing the components we want to configure.

We will create a repo, e.g. dev-env, containing the Vagrantfile and one subtree per external repo. The Vagrantfile will look like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = “ubuntu/trusty64”
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8080, guest: 8080 # core
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8081, guest: 8081 # service-auth
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8181, guest: 8181 # service-notifier
end
```

(We are assuming that our components will listen to different TCP ports.)

Then, we will use `git subtree` to add, update and push our components.

Depending on your project's characteristics and the team's organization, this solution may be a good fit or not.

I've written [an article](http://blog.moove-it.com/vagrant-multiple-projects/) giving more details on how to configure and use subtrees for this purposes.